# How to conditionally load language dependent Javascript file

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

How to export 2 variables conditionally?

These are 2 Javascript files to be used by language flag.

```
// text.fr.js
export const LOGIN_TITLE_fr = {
    title: 'Hello!', 
};

export const LOGIN_ERROR_fr = {
    err_msg: 'Error!', 
};

// text.en.js
export const LOGIN_TITLE_en = {
    title: 'Hello!', 
};

export const LOGIN_ERROR_en = {
    err_msg: 'Error!', 
};
```

This is file to conditionally import and then export 2 variables, which will be used by another file no listed here.

1) Case 1:

```
// text1.js
// No compiler error, but for 'fr', LOGIN_TITLE, LOGIN_ERROR are still en. Why?
import { LOGIN_TITLE_en, LOGIN_ERROR_en } from './text.en.js';
import { LOGIN_TITLE_ch, LOGIN_ERROR_ch } from './text.fr.js';

const LOGIN_TITLE = LOGIN_TITLE_en;
const LOGIN_ERROR = LOGIN_ERROR_en;

if (window.loi_language == 'fr') {
  const LOGIN_TITLE = LOGIN_TITLE_fr;
  const LOGIN_ERROR = LOGIN_ERROR_fr;
}


export {
  LOGIN_TITLE,
  LOGIN_ERROR
}
```

2) Case 2

```
// text2.js
// Error when loading at last line!!! 
import { LOGIN_TITLE_en, LOGIN_ERROR_en } from './text.en.js';
import { LOGIN_TITLE_ch, LOGIN_ERROR_fr } from './text.fr.js';


if (window.loi_language == 'fr') {
  const LOGIN_TITLE = LOGIN_TITLE_fr;
  const LOGIN_ERROR = LOGIN_ERROR_fr;
} else {
  const LOGIN_TITLE = LOGIN_TITLE_en;
  const LOGIN_ERROR = LOGIN_ERROR_en;
}


export {
  LOGIN_TITLE,
  LOGIN_ERROR    // Error: not defined.
}
```

Tried above 2 cases, none of them worked. Like to know what is the right way to export 2 variables depends on language.

Comment: I haven't dealt with localization before, but I don't believe this is the correct approach. Your .js is always going to be JS. There is no such thing as an English or French version of JavaScript. I belive that the localization files are separate from the JS file and the JS file applies the correct localization file.

Comment: define the variables with `let` since they are not `const`ant, use `let` only once per variable, and make sure that `window.loi_language` really is `fr`

Comment: Is there a typo in your question? 
`import { LOGIN_TITLE_fr, LOGIN_ERROR_fr } from './text.fr.js';`
instead of 
`import { LOGIN_TITLE_ch, LOGIN_ERROR_ch } from './text.fr.js';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are `const`-declaring the variables inside the block scopes, they don't affect the ones in the module scope. You'd need to use

```
let LOGIN_TITLE = LOGIN_TITLE_en;
let LOGIN_ERROR = LOGIN_ERROR_en;

if (window.loi_language == 'fr') {
  LOGIN_TITLE = LOGIN_TITLE_fr;
  LOGIN_ERROR = LOGIN_ERROR_fr;
}
```

I would however recommend to simplify into

```
// text.fr.js
export const LOGIN_TITLE = 'Bonjour!';
export const LOGIN_ERROR = 'Défaut!';
```

```
// text.en.js
export const LOGIN_TITLE = 'Hello!';
export const LOGIN_ERROR = 'Error!';
```

```
// text.js
import * as en from './text.en.js';
import * as fr from './text.fr.js';

const dict = window.loi_language == 'fr' ? fr : en;

export const LOGIN_TITLE = dict.LOGIN_TITLE;
export const LOGIN_ERROR = dict.LOGIN_ERROR;
```

Using the same names for the exports might at some point allow you to replace the dynamic `text.js` with a language-specific one right inside your module bundler.